# Can I use Aragon's UI components when building dapps on top of aragonOSx?

Tags: web3js, javascript, dapps, frontend, npm

I want to build my own custom DAO dapp on top of the new Aragon protocol, but would love to not have to create an entire new UI for it.

I was wondering if I could use Aragon's UI components to build my own? (https://github.com/aragon/apps/tree/develop/packages/ui-components)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Aragon is planning to release the UI components package to npm with its proper documentation, but not there yet.

However, you can use the UI components already by calling on `npm install https://github.com/aragon/apps/tree/develop/packages/ui-components` in your terminal when you're inside your codebase.

Once you install it, feel free to call `yarn storybook` and you'll be able to see the components you have at your disposal in the browser.